# Type object has not attribute 'get_or_create'

Tags: django, django-models

For reasons unknown only one (out of 18) of my Django models is throwing the error "type object 'LidarReading' has not attribute 'get_or_create'".  Model declaration is below.

```
class LidarReading(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    roll = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    pitch = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    yaw = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    coordinates = models.ForeignKey('FlightCoordinate', models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Call in Django [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) is as follows (note that 'flight_coordinate' is a FlightCoordinate model object created using get_or_create above):

```
lidar, created = LidarReading.get_or_create(value=t['lidarreading_value'],
    roll=t['lidarreading_roll'],
    pitch=t['lidarreading_pitch'],
    yaw=t['lidarreading_yaw'],
    coordinates=flight_coordinate,
    created=t['lidarreading_created'])
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forget `objects`

```
lidar, created = LidarReading.objects.get_or_create(value=t['lidarreading_value'],
    roll=t['lidarreading_roll'],
    pitch=t['lidarreading_pitch'],
    yaw=t['lidarreading_yaw'],
    coordinates=flight_coordinate,
    created=t['lidarreading_created'])
```